# Multiple ASP.NET MVC Applications; Server for shared UI Assets?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, user-interface, architecture

Given:
I am part of a team converting/rebuilding nearly 150 small ASP Classic, ASP.NET, & ASP.NET MVC intranet applications into a new single custom intranet application architecture solution.  We are targeting ASP.NET MVC 5.  The individual legacy apps will be converted to individual build-able product projects within the new solution/architecture.

Goal:
My goal is to provide a vision for the User Interface asset management and references.  This vision should incorporate shared assets, as well as unique product assets.

Questions:
For ease of deployment, I am considering a fairly flat shared UI project.  Then, for unique project asset needs, I was considering keeping them in their respective projects, rather than housing them in the UI project, somehow nested/organized by product.  Are there any opinions or concerns that I should consider with this approach?

Thanks,
Levi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this question begs for further clarification I will outline the strategy that worked for me while working for a large healthcare provider and had a similar daunting task.

#### CSS & Images

1. Use an **assets** domain to host css and images ( http://assets.mycompany.org )
2. If an assets domain is unavailable leverage IIS virtual directories
   to implement something like: http://mycompany.org/assets or
   http://mycompany.org/shared/assets at the global level.
3. Adopt product/project named stylesheets to easily identify over-rides within your architecture

   ```
   \my-org-root
   \my-org-root\assets\my-org-global.css
     # This is the global stylesheet that gets included for every HTML request
   \my-org-root\project-apples
   \my-org-root\project-apples\assets\css\apples.css
   \my-org-root\project-pears
   \my-org-root\project-pears\assets\css\pears.css
   \my-org-root\product-animals
   \my-org-root\product-animals\assets\css\animals.css
   \my-org-root\product-animals\lions\assets\css\lions.css
   \my-org-root\product-animals\tigers\assets\css\tigers.css
   ```
4. This won't come as a surprise: use [Sass](http://sass-lang.com). It will help maintain consistency and keep you from having an embolism.
5. Leverage partials as often as possible

   ```
   Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/_Product.cshtml", product);
   ```
6. Aggressively hunt down and destroy inline styles.
7. Be prepared to do a lot of cleanup.

#### Files & Video

If you have to support file uploads or self-hosted videos there are a handful of ways to proceed but they will largely be determined by your security policy.  Ideally, I'd recommend a hosted, secured solution like Amazon's S3.  These keeps BLOBS outside of your problem domain and keeps you focused on UI-based files.   If you cannot use a hosted solution then you'll need the *assets directory* strategy all the more.

```
\my-org-root\project-apples
\my-org-root\project-apples\assets\video\FILE-ID-REF.ext
\my-org-root\project-apples\assets\files\2014\1\22\FILE-ID-REF.ext
# or, perhaps more simply
\my-org-root\project-apples\assets\files\FILE-ID-REF.ext
```

Need clarification?  Just ask.